# Poltergeist using FromSqlRaw with EF Core5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have to retrieve this data from 2 different databases within the same instance

[image: sql]

For which I put that same SQL statement in my code

```
public int ImportarUTEs()
{
  try
  {
    int registrosAñadidos = 0;

    var registrosSAP = _contextSAP.Licitadores
     .FromSqlRaw(@"select  distinct ot.IDLICITADOR as IdLicitador,
                        l.cardcode as CodigoSAP,
                        ic.cardname as Nombre
                    from ofertantes ot INNER JOIN licitadores l on     ot.idlicitador=l.idlicitador
                     inner join ofertas o on o.codigoanalizada=ot.codigoanalizada
                     inner join Fulcrum.dbo.OCRD ic on l.cardcode=ic.cardcode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                    where year(o.fechapres)>=2015 AND   
                        ot.idlicitador in(
                            select IDLICITADOR  from LICITADORES
                            GROUP by IDLICITADOR
                            HAVING  COUNT(*)>1 
                            )
                    order by IdLicitador, CodigoSAP")
                .ToList();
```

But what is my surprise when I see the result obtained

[image: momtaje]

When you have to obtain the 2 records corresponding to LicitasorID 2368, I see that I get 3 records where [8] repeats the value of [6] and instead of being the value corresponding to LicitadorID 2881 and CodigoSAP 430FULCRUM, it assigns the value LicitadorID 2368. But the strangest thing is that when it is time to collect the values of IdLicitador 3150 it turns out that it does the same thing, IdLicitador 3150 and CodigoSAP 430FULCRUM the [10 ] turns it into IdLicitador 2368 and CodigoSAP 430FULCRUM.

That is, for some reason that I can't understand the value obtained in the EF Core 5 project is not the same as the one obtained in the SQL Server instance and I can't think of what to do about it

Any idea, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to define the primary key in LicitadoresSAP entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LicitadorSAP>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.IdLicitador, c.CodigoSAP });
```

Now works fine